# Suffrage Badge not earned

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I recently fulfilled ed the criteria for earning the `Suffrage` badge, but it is not being shown on my profile. From another badge, `Vox Populi`, it is confirmed that I have completed the 30 votes criteria and that badge is now not shown in the available badges list.

Does it takes time to show the earned badge?

Here are the screenshots for proof.
[image: All Badges]
[image: Earned Badges]
[image: Vox Populi Badge]

Comment: It takes time.  "Recently" does very little to help us help you.

Comment: Recently means now it's about 30 mins

Comment: Come back tomorrow.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Does it takes time to show the earned badge?

Yes, it does. Badges are awarded through a scheduled job - some every 5 minutes, some hourly, some daily.

Be patient.

Answer (score 4):

The badges don't appear immediately.

The badges are awarded by scripts, that run at different times.

I don't see either badge on your profile yet. Give it a little time.

I'm not entirely sure about this, but: I believe that "Vox Populi" and "Suffrage" should appear within 24 hours.