# How much time it will take award the Vox Populi badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, profile-page

I was trying to get the Vox Populi badge and reached the maximum votes per day but the badge was not updated immediately. I was wondering how much time it's taking to update the profile information.

[image]

Comment: According to your profile you've only ever cast 2 votes... Have you definitely voted 40 times today?

Comment: Please note that votes on comments, Documentation examples and SO meta do not count.

Comment: I have edited the question and it shows I have earned 6 badges but its not updated in above tab yet. I tried clearing the browser cache also but its not getting updated.

@MariaDeleva votes on comments does count.

Comment: @Bharath No, votes on comments DO NOT count. Where did you read that?

Comment: Suffrage badge got updated in 33min from the 30th vote cast.

Comment: Sorry MariaDeleva & @rene I was wrong

Comment: Yes, you are, no problem, that can happen. I guess @MariaDeleva will forgive you but don't let it happen again ;)

Comment: Do note that [not all badge scripts run simultaneously](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90725/vox-populi-badge-but-no-suffrage-badge). Some only run once a day.

Comment: This is a dupe: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320528/suffrage-badge-not-earned/320530#320530